# Overriding -performSelector: in UIBarButtonItem Subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, subclass, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to subclass `UIBarButtonItem` to add some special functionality. I need the `barButtonItem` to toggle its appearance when touched, and am therefore attempting to override `performSelector:`.

When I use the code below, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2 ...)`

```
-(id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object1 withObject:(id)object2
{
    // Do something

    return [super performSelector:aSelector withObject:object1 withObject:object2];
}
```

My guess is that I am either wrongly attempting to override `performSelector:` (is there another way?) or incorrectly calling the method on `super`.

After searching for a solution for 3+ hours I have found nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
The following works:

```
@implementation CustomBarButtonItem

- (void)setTarget:(id)target
{
    _realTarget = target;
    super.target = self;
}

- (void)setAction:(SEL)action
{
    _realAction = action;
    super.action = @selector(pressed);
}

- (void)pressed
{
    [self doCustom]; // implement this somewhere
    [_realTarget performSelector:_realAction withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

Unfortunately I wanted to toggle between having a `customView` and the normal `UIBarButtonItem` look by setting `self.customView = nil` which only works sometimes. But that is a-whole-nother question. Thanks all.

I will wait a little longer to choose a best answer to see if there are better solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably better to implement this functionality using a simple `UIView` that you can simply modify in any given way.

`UIBarButtonItem` does provide a way for initializing based on a custom UIView:

`- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView`

You could then tell the `UIView` to change its appearance based on the touch events fired by the `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Could I do this with a subclass though?

Comment: You could automatically instantiate the appropriate (dynamic) `UIView` on initializing your `UIBarButtonItem` (and subsequently set the target of `self` (the `UIBarButtonItem`) to your custom `UIView`).

Comment: @Fscheidl Sorry, I should have been more specific. I want to toggle the button between the normal `UIBarButtonItem` look and a `customView`. So if I change the target of `self` I'll have to maintain references to the old target (and action) and toggle them depending on the view? This seems unnessecarrily complicated unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding `performSelector:` is definitely not the right way to go.
The class may use `performSelector:` to do various things, not only the Target-Action part.

Unfortunately, there are no public methods which are being executed before the `performSelector` for the target action is executed.

You could, however implement the action using Target-Action in the view controller, or you could override a private method.

Also, it would be helpful to know what you mean with 'special functionality'.

Comment: Okay, I had previously implemented this in the view controller with target-action. But since I would be using it a lot, I figured it would be easier (in the future) if I had the custom subclass. So in other words this is not possible? Unfortunate.
And by "special functionality" I meant "I need the barButtonItem to change its appearance when touched" and stay that way.

Comment: @JoSmith Wait a second, I'll try to find a private method, where you could implement it. It's worth to point out that Apple may not approve it for the App Store though. I don't think there will be any problems, but I cannot guarantee it.

Comment: Really? I thought that the use of any private method would result in rejection. Awesome if that's not true.

Comment: @JoSmith I thought that too, I asked a company for advice on a control once, they told me to override a private method, and their app is on the app store.

Comment: @JoSmith After seeing Fscheidl's answer, you should probably go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Add up/down handlers

   ```
   CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
   loginButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
   UIColor *topColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255 green:255/255 blue:255/255 alpha:0.9];
   UIColor *middleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255 green:130.0/255 blue:244.0/255 alpha:1.0];
   UIColor *bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
   gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor,
                      (id)middleColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
   gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.05f],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7],
                         nil];
   gradient.frame = [[loginButton layer] bounds];
   gradient.cornerRadius = 4.0;
   gradient.borderWidth = 0.5;
   [loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [loginButton.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0]; 
   [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginTouchDown:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginTouchUp:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
   ```
2. In handlers I would use gradient layers or simple layers (prepared before) to do what you need about appearance.

   ```
   - (IBAction)loginTouchDown:(id)sender
   {
           CAGradientLayer *gradient = [loginButton.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0];
           UIColor *topColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
           UIColor *middleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
           UIColor *bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
           gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor, (id)middleColor.CGColor,
                              (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
   }

   - (IBAction)loginTouchUp:(id)sender
   {
           CAGradientLayer *gradient = [loginButton.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0];
           UIColor *topColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255 green:255/255 blue:255/255 alpha:0.9];
           UIColor *middleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255 green:130.0/255 blue:244.0/255 alpha:1.0];
           UIColor *bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
           gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor,
                              (id)middleColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
   }
   ```